# set rails console stack backtrace limit permanently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stack-trace, rails-console, backtrace

`rails console` by default boots with `context.back_trace_limit=16`, which can be changed to whatever you want simply by typing `context.back_trace_limit=n`. The problem is you have to type it each time you boot `rails c`. Where do I change the `context.back_trace_limit` permanently? Some more reading on rails console configuration appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to create/edit your `~/.irbrc` with the following:

```
IRB.conf[:BACK_TRACE_LIMIT]= 20
```

To be taken into account:

- The options must be uppercased
- This option is changing not only the
  rails console, but the normal "irb" behavior (the rails console uses
  irb to run)
- This setting is global, and not per project

Reference http://rakeroutes.com/blog/customize-your-irb/

**Update for Rails 5**

In Rails 5 the command `context.back_trace_limit=20` will fail.

In the console you need to use the command `conf.back_trace_limit = 10` for the current session.

For permanent changes, writing `IRB.conf[:BACK_TRACE_LIMIT]= 20` in your `~/.irbrc` is still valid.

You can see the current settings by calling `conf`

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Could you share where do you know about it from?

Comment: This no longer works on Rails5.  The `wtf?` method that comes with `pry` can help, but only gets you ten instead of one.