# Set the stack trace limit in rinari-console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs, console, rinari

As can be seen from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295935/set-rails-console-stack-backtrace-limit-permanently) the back trace limit in Rails console is set by passing a new value to `context.back_trace_limit`. While this can be set in the .irbc file, I'd much rather Emacs set it for me, since I don't normally use `irb` outside of the editor, and my .emacs is synched across various systems I use.

Is there a way to pass in this value when I start rinari-console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire definition of the rinari-console function in [rinari.el](https://github.com/eschulte/rinari/blob/master/rinari.el) is:

```
(defun rinari-console (&optional edit-cmd-args)
  "Run a Rails console in a compilation buffer.
The buffer will support command history and links between errors
and source code.  Optional prefix argument EDIT-CMD-ARGS lets the
user edit the console command arguments."
  (interactive "P")
  (let* ((default-directory (rinari-root))
         (command (rinari--maybe-wrap-with-ruby
                   (rinari--wrap-rails-command "console"))))

    ;; Start console in correct environment.
    (when rinari-rails-env
      (setq command (concat command " " rinari-rails-env)))

    ;; For customization of the console command with prefix arg.
    (setq command (if edit-cmd-args
                      (read-string "Run Ruby: " (concat command " "))
                    command))
    (with-current-buffer (run-ruby command "rails console")
      (rinari-launch)))
```

So there's no built-in way to pass values to the irb session. However, I've stopped using Rinari, so am no longer working on a solution.