# How to get a stack trace in Rails?

Tags: stack-trace, backtrace

Ruby on Rails shows only 1 line or two lines of stack trace.  I need to see the stack trace.  How do I turn it on?

`Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers!` does not have any effect.  I am using Rails 4.2 and Ruby 2.3

Comment: this can be an IRB problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295935/set-rails-console-stack-backtrace-limit-permanently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/.irbrc`

IRB.conf[:BACK_TRACE_LIMIT]= 32767